# Spring 3.2 + Jersey. Context initialization failed. Works with Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have been following the tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/). I can get it to work exactly as is. However, if I attempt to upgrade to Spring 3.2.1

```
[#|2013-03-11T13:07:35.780-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\MFrancis\Dropbox\Code\ProductionQueue\target\ProductionQueue-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\fettergroup\production\queue\rest\PaymentService.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super
```

I also got the example to work with spring 3.1.4. So something had to change between 3.1 and 3.2 that is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you have updated all Spring components to new version. This is class incompatible version error, might be due to different version of compiled classes.